# Memory Usage: GET vs POST?

Tags: post, memory, server, get, request

[PHP7](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484217290) by Apress says that :

> Why does the Google search engine send information via GET instead of
>   POST (which would have hidden the information)? The main reason is to
>   save server memory. Just think of the millions of requests that Google
>   has for information. If all of these requests resided in memory, the
>   servers would soon crash. Also, since the user is doing a “public”
>   search for information, there is no reason to hide the information.

---

*I want to understand that how memory usage is different for GET and POST request params. I have read that in CGI scripts, POST params are passed as standard input while GET params are passed as a query string. Still, the memory usage should be same for the param, that can be passed through both GET and POST.*

Comment: That is complete nonsense. Do yourself a favor and burn the book.

Comment: @JJJ while the claim that memory is the main reason is a complete nonsense, it do have some relation in which GETs are cache-able and POSTs are not. you do know what it means if a 100 same POSTs and a 100 same GETs is like on the server? as the main reason to why google use GETs instead of POSTs, i suspect that it is because GETs are indexable

Answer (score 1):

GET method is cache-able by proxies and web browsers, so a lot of GET request did not reach the originating server, therefore "saving" resources like bandwidth, cpu power, ram, etc

while POST method is not cache-able by design, therefore the server need to process all POST requests, which means using more resources.